# How can I enable File Sharing & Remote Login from a utility or script?

Tags: security, permission, ssh, sudo

I would like to leave File Sharing and Remote Login off normally, but be able to remotely turn them on if and when I need them.  The commands to do this are easily found online.

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist EnabledServices -array disk
```

and

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

The problem is that they require a password being entered, and I can't do them through SSH if I have SSH turned off.

I have no problem finding an alternate way of triggering commands, but those remote triggers won't allow me to enter a password, and saving a password is horribly insecure.   Is there any other way?

I have seen various apps install helpers that prompt for the user's admin password once and then seem to forever have the rights to perform a specific action or set of actions.  How can I do this?